# TypeScript tls.TLSSocket() complains about lacking a "socket" argument

Tags: typescript, sockets, ssl

I'm mucking around building a very basic IRC bot, and am connecting to the IRC server using raw sockets. I'd written the bot in plain Javascript originally, and am redoing it in TypeScript, but have run into a bit of a weird issue when connecting over TLS (it all works fine over a non-secure connection). The source code of my bot lives [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/VirtualWolf/weatherbot/src) and the specific bit I'm having issues with is [here](https://bitbucket.org/VirtualWolf/weatherbot/src/7e0590252e2b9e76e1efa4d9a2553f4f6f46911f/src/lib/weatherbot.ts#lines-32):

```
[...]
this.client = this.tlsEnabled
    // @ts-ignore
    ? new TLSSocket()
    : new Socket();

this.client.connect(this.port, this.host, () => {
    this.sendInitialConnectionMessages();
});
[...]
```

If I don't have the `@ts-ignore` line, VS Code and `tsc` complain about the `new TLSSocket()` call:

> Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0. An argument for 'socket' was not provided.

And indeed, the type definition says it requires a `socket` argument at minimum.

However, if I supply that, either via `new TLSSocket(new Socket())` or `const socket = new Socket()` and `new TLSSocket(socket)`, the script immediately exits without hitting the `this.client.connect()` call. If I tell `tsc` to ignore the lack of arguments to `TLSSocket()` as above, everything works perfectly and the bot successfully connects to the server via TLS!

I assume I'm doing something dumb here, but I'm just not sure what. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems the library you use and the definition file has a version mismatch. Try to `go to definition` and locate where the definition file resides.

Comment: It's not a separate library but the core Node.js [tls](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket) module. Your comment made me realise I hadn't installed `@types/node`, but sadly that made no difference. I checked the definition location and it's where I'd expect in `node_modules/@types/node/tls.d.ts`.

Comment: Well it seems typescripts whining about constructor signature is right. According to [this](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_new_tls_tlssocket_socket_options) document it requires a socket. So your node installation may be outdated?

Comment: Yeah agreed, I'm just really baffled as to how it works if I simply tell tsc to ignore that bit. :D Node installation is the absolute latest LTS, 12.13.1, and the docs for that version are identical to 13.x that you linked to.

Comment: Check your package json if `node_interop` package exists. It seems a popular library that exports a `TLSSocket` class with parameterless constructor.

Comment: It does not, I'm afraid! I'm tempted to just leave the `@ts-ignore` in place and go do something else, heh. Cheers for the suggestions anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! After doing a bunch more searching and finding examples, I rewrote the connection functionality from what's in my original question to this:

```
this.client = this.tlsEnabled
    ? tls.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port}, () => this.sendInitialConnectionMessages())
    : net.connect({host: this.host, port: this.port}, () => this.sendInitialConnectionMessages());
```

And everything works as expected now.